How to make Marker visible by the cameras? （old ignition gazebo）
The marker generated in the Gazebo simulation is visible on the GUI but does not appear through the camera.
In Gazebo Classic, a method has been proposed to make the LiDAR laser visible through the camera. Is it possible to visualize the marker in a similar way?
How to make GpuRay visible by the cameras?
